# Extract links from iframe - Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink

I am trying to extract the links in from a page loaded into Iframe that is not of the same origin as the main web page.  The javascript console for FF and Chromium doesn't report any errors. Both browsers also do not extract the links from the webpage in the iframe.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe name='iframe' id='iframe' src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>

 <script>
  var a = document.getElementById('iframe')
  var links = a.getElementsByTagName('a');

  document.write(links.length);
  for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    document.write(links[i].href);
  } 
</script>
<div id="results">results</div>
```

Comment: Of course not, that would be huge security violation.

Comment: It is not posible in Javascript when there are different domains. The only way you can do something like that, is to create a server side HTML parser/scraper depending whether the iframe content is generated statically on the server or dynamically on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done because security.

You don't get errors because you query on the `iframe` element and not its `contentDocument`.

```html
<iframe name='iframe' id='iframe' src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>

<script>
  var a = document.getElementById('iframe');
  var links = a.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('a');
</script>
```

Comment: I had tried that code previously but it didn't work either. If add these two links after you example:  
  document.write(links[0]); 
  document.write(links.length); 
I get "undefined" and "0" as the output.

Comment: That code is to illustrate the security error you get. It should show this: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: There is no way to get those links.